# get the device information programmatically in j2me

Tags: java-me

I want to fetch some information in J2ME programmatically. Whether it is possible to get all the information. I had done some search and got this link:-
http://developers.sun.com/mobility/m...ies/index.html

But it is giving be only few data like configuration.platform. I want all the data.

Features

- Device platform. (android, iphone, blackberry, windowsmobile)
- Maker of this device.
- Model of the device.
- Version of the OS on this device
- Country device is from (obtained by querying the SIM card)
- Country the current locale is set to.
- Country the language is set to
- Country the user is currently in (comes from Sim card).
- Current carrier (comes from sim card)
- Current mobile network code (comes from sim card)
- Type of data connection (wifi, umts, gprs, evdo, ...)
- Latitude and Longitude returned by the location provider
- device PIN number